# Taxonomy and Prototype in Spree

Tags: spree

I want to know briefly few spree terms like Taxonomy , Prototype , properties, and option type .

Consider If I am making website for ordering food online , than Taxonomy can be "Chinese","Italian","indian"..etc...what should be prototype ? and properties or option type is possible...

Also I want to create a side menu look like this



**Grab by chinese

 -Noodles
 
-mamos**

Grab by Indian
 
-Dosa

 -bread

So What should be taxonomy and prototype here in this case ? also how to achieve this type of thing using admin Gui in spree like creating taxanomy...than ..... ?

Answer (score 0):

"Chinese" and "Indian" would be the taxonomies, while "Noodles", "Mamos", "Dosa" and "Bread" would be taxons nested inside those taxonomies.

For more information, please read [the "Taxons and Taxonomies" section of the Products guide.](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/products.html#taxons-and-taxonomies)